# Import data from cvs excel file to DB2 (mac terminal)

Tags: import, db2

I have a cvs excel file on my computer and I would like to import the data from the file into a table in DB2. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you

Comment: Have you tested the IMPORT command? Any specific issues? What Db2 platform?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to connect to the Db2-database at the terminal, then you have several ways to add content into the Db2-database . Each method has different requirements (e.g. the type of the Db2-client, the privileges of your userid , the target Db2-server version and capabilities and platform, and many others...) , and you have to understand the requirements before you can properly use any of the commands. Most of these commands require the *fat client* of Db2 to be installed on the workstation. If your workstations lack a fat client and if you can transfer the file to a location accessible to the Db2-server then you can also use a stored procedure to run these commands at the Db2-server, but run this from your terminal, see [ADMIN_CMD](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=procedure-admin-cmd-run-administrative-commands).

All of these options are fully documented in the free online Db2 Knowledge Centre, and each has many special command-line options to control the exact behaviour of the action. Therefore careful study is needed, along with careful rehearsal and testing. Stackoverflow is not a substitute for your education or your training. So it is wise to study the documentation before asking questions that are already answered in the documentation. Sometimes you need to study all the linked pages in the documentation and rehearse each option to fully understand how to use these things for best advantage.

Your options include:

- The **import** command. Slow (logged), and flexible with many options.
  Details [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-import)
- The **ingest** command. Faster than import and also programmable. Details [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-ingest).
- The **load** command. Fastest but requires skill and experience to properly harness its power properly especially in high-availability environments. Details [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-load).
- Another option is to use **external tables**, if your Db2-server-platform-and-version supports external tables and if it has the necessary fixes already applied. This lets you represent a flat file (e.g. a CSV file)  as a  table in the database. In this case, you can use `INSERT INTO target-table ....select ... from your-external-table`. Requires skill and competence. Details [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-external-table) and many related pages.